# what is the purpose of the files in this directory: /var/lib/apt/lists?

Tags: var

linux lubuntu 
HD4000
intel ivy-bridge
8gb 1600 ram.

I am getting a duplicate entry error message from synaptic package manager 
and it says the problem is there. I am wondering a few things:

1. What this directory is.
2. Whether it safe to simply delete the offending duplicates from there.
3. Whether this is a useful new discovery... Is this where all the packages I have no use for end up and something I can edit to suit my fancy in the long run? It would be nice to be able to reduce the clutter in my package manager. Especially find a way to get rid of all the 32 bit stuff or older versions of programs I have downloaded manually elsewhere.

I had meant to post this in linux! So if this is wrong place let me know and I will move it there!

Comment: Your question probably has a better home on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) but please [search](http://askubuntu.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From **man apt-get**

> ```
> /var/lib/apt/lists/
> Storage area for state information for each package resource
> specified in sources.list(5) Configuration Item: Dir::State::Lists.
>
> /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/
> Storage area for state information in transit. Configuration Item:
> Dir::State::Lists (partial will be implicitly appended)
> ```

So it's something that **apt-get update** can recreate